# last_insert_rowid in sqlite - two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

I got two tables, one of which is a helper of the other. The table "reviews" has a column which is an integer referencing to the id of the film of that review in the table "films". Is there a way to, after inserting in the table "films" a new film, use the last_insert_rowid in the table "reviews"?

I'm using SQLITE; I've seen uses with max(id) but it might not be as reliable. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just simply use it as a value in your next insert, à la

```
INSERT INTO films (name) values ('Shark!');
INSERT INTO reviews (filmId,review) values (last_insert_rowid(), 'Good!');
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/edf2d/2).

Comment: Thanks! I thought it only worked for the same table. Also, interesting site SQL Fiddle! I dind't know it existed.

Comment: It's worth noting that last_insert_rowid() acts as a quasi-global value - it stores the rowid from the previous INSERT operation, across the current database connection.